# questions about using mod_rewrite for clean URLs

Tags: database, .htaccess, url

I would like to use mod_rewrite in .htaccess to rewrite a URL such as, http://www.companysite.com/gallery.php?galid=1&desc=blah%20blah%20blah to http://www.companysite.com/gallery/1/blah-blah-blah

Using the rough code **Loren** gave me:

```
#Perform a 301 redirect from the old URL to the new URL  
RewriteRule ^gallery.php?galid=([0-9]+)&desc=(.*) http://www.companysite.com/gallery/$1/$ [R=301,L]  

#Rewrite new URL to the proper internal URL
RewriteRule ^gallery/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ ^gallery.php?galid=$1&desc=$2  [L]
```

if the querystring for `desc` is `blah%20blah%20blah`, how will that be rewritten?  Ideally I would like `desc` to be rewritten as blah-blah-blah.  How do I do that?

Comment: I edited this question to try and make it "on topic" so it will be re-opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this solely with an htaccess file.

You SHOULD change the links in your site to reflect the new rewritten URLs and put 301 redirects in place for the old urls pointing to the new

In regards to pages already indexed with google, you can perform 301 redirects from the old URL to the new URL - this will tell google that the old url has been updated to the newly rewritten url, which should prevent you from losing ranking/indexing of that page

If someone clicks on the link with the old url it will NOT automatically be rewritten, unless you have 301 redirects in place which will then automatically redirect the user to the properly rewritten URL

Please let me know if I can be anymore specific in the areas covered above.

Once you have created your new URL structure and setup the 301's to point the old urls to the new urls I recommend you submit an OLD sitemap to google, they will crawl the old urls, detect the 301's and update the index with your newly rewritten URL - i've done this a million times in the past and its worked flawlessly

**301 old URL to new URL**

this is a sample of a very simplistic 301 redirect via the htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^contact_us\.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/contact_us.html [R=301]
```

**Example of rewrite using your links above**

Here is a quick and dirty example of doing a 301 on an old url first, then rewriting the new url to the internal url structure - whipped this up quick - apologize if any mistakes

```
#Perform a 301 redirect from the old URL to the new URL
RewriteRule ^gallery.php?galid=([0-9]+)&desc=(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/gallery/$1/$2 [R=301,L]

#Rewrite new URL to the proper internal URL
RewriteRule ^gallery/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ ^gallery.php?galid=$1&desc=$2  [L]
```

**Keep in Mind**

Rewriting `/gallery.php?galid=1&desc=blah%20blah%20blah` to `/gallery/1/blah-blah-blah` will require you account for the spaces in your `blah blah blah` - if you rewrite to `blah-blah-blah` then when you receive the querystring `desc` it will receive `blah-blah-blah` which is different than `blah blah blah`

know what i mean?

**Resources**

**[This is a good article on URL rewrites and redirects](http://searchengineland.com/url-rewrites-and-redirects-part1-16574)**

Comment: My previous comment was unclear, but to rehash, you are awesome thank you for this great response.  I want the resulting URL to be `/gallery/1/blah-blah-blah...` with the words separated by hyphens instead of the %20 or white space. I won't know how long desc will be, if that matters.  How do I accomplish that?